# Chinese character input in text field

Tags: html, chinese-locale

I have made a small website, and I want to forced that the 1st input type="text" can only be filled with Chinese Characters, without changing the keyboard layout. The 2nd input type="text" just normal alphabet. I tried to add lang="zh-Hans", but that was to easy thinking, is this possible Anyone has a suggestion.

thanks for feedback

```
<code>
<form action="expressionadded_cn.php" method="post">

        <table class="centertable">

        <tr><td><input type="text" name="chinese" placeholder="Chinese" size="36" value="" autocomplete="off" />
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td><input type="text" name="pinyin" placeholder="Pinyin" size="36" value="" autocomplete="off" />
        </td></tr>
        </table>

    </form>

</code>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Can I Make oninput() Trigger Only When Chinese Characters, Not IME Keystrokes, Are Entered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53893492/how-can-i-make-oninput-trigger-only-when-chinese-characters-not-ime-keystroke)